# Devo estender de uma classe abstrata ou de uma concreta?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, classes-abstratas

Quando precisar estender uma classe, seguindo o conceito de Orientação a Objetos, devo estender meu código de uma classe abstrata ou de uma não abstrata? Qual é a melhor prática a aderir?

Comment: Essa garantiu minha pratinha de [tag:orientação-a-objetos] :)

Comment: Ai sim hein @bigown! Meus parabéns! Um dia chego nesse nível, rs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não existe melhor opção, você estende a classe que você precisa estender. Se ela é abstrata ou não, não faz diferença para seu código a não ser pelo fato que uma abstrata possivelmente terá métodos não implementados e sua nova classe terá a obrigação de criar uma implementação para todos os métodos abstratos contidos na classe (os não abstratos são opcionais).

Se quer saber se é melhor criar uma classe abstrata ou não, aí depende do que você deseja. Uma classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada, ela é criada para ser usada como um modelo para outras classes. As não abstratas podem ser usadas como modelos mas também podem ser instanciadas diretamente. Você só torna uma classe abstrata se deseja proibir sua instanciação (o que é obrigado, se ela é incompleta).

Embora eu acho que herança só deveria ser feita de classe abstrata (ou interface ou *trait* se a linguagem permitir). Claro que existem exceções para a regra, mas parece mais adequado, mas tenha isso como minha opinião, e que vejo se ampliando.

Claro que se a classe possui métodos sem implementação, funcionando como contratos para as classes derivadas seguirem, ou seja, funcionam como se fosse uma interface, aí a classe obrigatoriamente tem que ser abstrata. Não é possível instanciar classes com métodos sem implementação.

Por exemplo, se tiver uma classe `Pessoa` e as derivadas dela `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`. Provavelmente você não precisa e talvez nem possa instanciar só a a `Pessoa`. Ela provavelmente é incompleta. Você só criou ela para dar suporte às duas (quem sabe outras) derivadas que citei. Ela é quase uma interface, mas provavelmente tem variáveis e alguns métodos com implementação. Então `Pessoa` provavelmente deve ser abstrata.

Lembrando que só pode herdar de **uma** classe. Abstrata ou não. Interface pode várias. Pelo menos na maioria das linguagens.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se tratando de manutenção e legibilidade de código, as interfaces são uma melhor indicação que as classes abstratas, ou isso independe dessa escolha?

Comment: Depende, claro. Em geral interfaces são melhores, mas há casos que não pode usá-las sob pena de perder uma estrutura básica de um tipo. Não dá para trabalhar só com interfaces e manter o reuso de código. No fundo classe abstrata deve ser comparada com classes concretas. Ela é a classe concreta que precisa omitir alguns detalhes de implementação.

Comment: "Só pode herdar uma classe" a menos que a linguagem permita herança múltipla. :) Eu também acrescentaria "pense três vezes antes de criar uma hierarquia, tenha a certeza de que a subclasse e a superclasse respeitam a relação IS-A, e quando for criar métodos na superclasse para reuso de código pense bem se eles realmente valem para todas as subclasses" (eu erro muito nesses pontos).

Comment: @Piovezan é verdade, é que a maioria das perguntas dele tem a *tag* [tag:java], então fui nessa onda. Já dei outras respostas, até pra ele mesmo onde falo sobre a hierarquia, mas vale o registro aqui. Tem muito abuso de herança, alguns casos que são enormes absurdos. Errar em casos que parece ser um *is-a*, é uma coisa, errar qdo nem chega perto é outra :) As pessoas precisam parar de pensar em herança como *default* e sim como última solução.