# Por que usar Interface aos invês de Herança?

Tags: java, herança, interface

Eu gostaria de saber por que em java geralmente se deve dar prioridade para o uso de interfaces,ao invês de herança com classes.

Comment: São coisas diferentes e, portanto, usadas para fins diferentes. Interface é apenas para ter certeza que tal classe tem tais propriedades (tipagem), herença serve para o mesmo mas também passa essas propriedades para a classe que herdará

Comment: Também úteis: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87488/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166530/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89236/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101

Answer (score 6):

Uma boa razão é que uma herança é um acoplamento muito mais forte que uma interface.

[Acoplamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) é quando partes do seu código estão dependentes. Imagine que você tem uma função que calcula as coordenadas de uma nave na tela. Ela possivelmente é dependente das funções java.math para realizar os cálculos. Então ela possui certo grau de acoplamento com java.math. É um conceito relativo e que procuramos diminuir nos nossos programas, pois um alto acoplamento exige que uma mudança em um lugar gere mudanças em outros. Imagine neste exemplo que o java altere os argumentos da função sqrt. Todos que a usam esta função terão de realizar alterações em seu código.

Acoplamentos podem ser causados por composição (um objeto é composto / possui um campo de outro objeto), por uso de funções de outro objeto, pelo uso de interfaces e pela herança.

Considera-se a herança contendo um alto grau de acoplamento, pois qualquer coisa que você fizer na classe pai irá afetar inevitavelmente a classe filha. E a classe filha pode ter acesso as "entranhas" da classe pai, usando os campos e métodos protegidos, então a chance de ser atingida é maior. O [contrato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) entre a classe pai e filha é mais íntimo e difícil de definir. Em outras palavras. Se você apenas "chama" um método de um objeto, você o faz pois acredita que aquele método se comportará de tal forma e retornará dado valor previsto. No caso da classe pai, a classe filha possui mais recursos para manipular dados da classe pai, exigindo do desenvolvedor mais conhecimento e aumentando a change de gerar bugs.

Por outro lado, interfaces você não compartilha campos e métodos. Apenas a assinatura (o contrato da classe). Então a única alteração que afeta a classe filha é a mudança de assinatura, que a própria linguagem garantirá, em tempo de compilação, que as classes filhas sejam revistas e corrigidas.

Outro fator relacionado ao acoplamento, porém mais ligado a análise é que idealmente você deve usar heranças do java para implementar o conceito de herança da análise. Isto é, em dado domínio um aluno pode ser uma pessoa e pode fazer sentido que o aluno compartilhe as funções e campos de pessoa. Porém quando se usa herança para reaproveitar algoritmos e campos que não fazem parte do modelo de análise (por exemplo, a classe de aluno será pai da classe curso, pois o curso precisar de informações e métodos para calcular a matrícula do aluno), acaba-se usando um recurso poderoso da linguagem para solucionar um problema que poderia ter outra abordagem com menor acoplamento.

Por fim, quando queremos definir os limites entre os módulos da aplicação, estamos definindo os [componentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering) desta aplicação, e interfaces são mais adequadas para este caso.

Espero ter ajudado,

abs

Comment: Deve se atentar ao detalhe que em algumas linguagens não se aceita herança múltipla, levando a importância das interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Depende muito do que você que abstrair. Em casos onde se que padronizar assinaturas de métodos, pode ser usado a interface, já em casos onde se que reaproveitar os atributos de uma classe e também implementar ou sobrescrever métodos via polimorfismo, pode ser melhor utilizar a herança.